# Uncaught TypeError: vector.subSelf is not a function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a simple tank game based off of [Nemesis](https://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2012/06/how-build-first-person-shooter-browser-threejs-and-webglhtml5-canvas), Isaac Sukin's game for AngelHack. Actually, what I'm trying to change is simple. I have a file named "Tank.obj" in a folder called "models".

I simple want to replace the cube with the enemy, with a model for a tank ("Tank.obj).

I keep on getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: vector.subSelf is not a function

I am not sure what this even means.....

Just so you know:
I have a **fully** updated Three.js file, and the OBJLoader.js is in my file hierarchy.

Here is the altered files (It's not altered that much, though):

```js
/**
 * Notes:
 * - Coordinates are specified as (X, Y, Z) where X and Z are horizontal and Y
 *   is vertical
 */

var map = [ // 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], // 0
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,], // 1
           [1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,], // 2
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1,], // 3
           [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1,], // 4
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,], // 5
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,], // 6
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,], // 7
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,], // 8
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,], // 9
           ], mapW = map.length, mapH = map[0].length;

// Semi-constants
var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
 ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
 UNITSIZE = 250,
 WALLHEIGHT = UNITSIZE / 3,
 MOVESPEED = 100,
 LOOKSPEED = 0.075,
 BULLETMOVESPEED = MOVESPEED * 5,
 NUMAI = 5,
 PROJECTILEDAMAGE = 20;
// Global vars
var t = THREE, scene, cam, renderer, controls, clock, projector, model, skin;
var runAnim = true, mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 }, kills = 0, health = 100;
var healthCube, lastHealthPickup = 0;
/*
var finder = new PF.AStarFinder({ // Defaults to Manhattan heuristic
 allowDiagonal: true,
}), grid = new PF.Grid(mapW, mapH, map);
*/

// Initialize and run on document ready
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('body').append('<div id="intro">Click to start</div>');
 $('#intro').css({width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT}).one('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).fadeOut();
  init();
  setInterval(drawRadar, 1000);
  animate();
 });
 /*
 new t.ColladaLoader().load('models/Yoshi/Yoshi.dae', function(collada) {
  model = collada.scene;
  skin = collada.skins[0];
  model.scale.set(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  model.position.set(0, 5, 0);
  scene.add(model);
 });
 */
});

// Setup
function init() {
 clock = new t.Clock(); // Used in render() for controls.update()
 projector = new t.Projector(); // Used in bullet projection
 scene = new t.Scene(); // Holds all objects in the canvas
 scene.fog = new t.FogExp2(0xD6F1FF, 0.0005); // color, density
 
 // Set up camera
 cam = new t.PerspectiveCamera(60, ASPECT, 1, 10000); // FOV, aspect, near, far
 cam.position.y = UNITSIZE * .2;
 scene.add(cam);
 
 // Camera moves with mouse, flies around with WASD/arrow keys
 controls = new t.FirstPersonControls(cam);
 controls.movementSpeed = MOVESPEED;
 controls.lookSpeed = LOOKSPEED;
 controls.lookVertical = false; // Temporary solution; play on flat surfaces only
 controls.noFly = true;

 // World objects
 setupScene();
 
 // Artificial Intelligence
 setupAI();
 
 // Handle drawing as WebGL (faster than Canvas but less supported)
 renderer = new t.WebGLRenderer();
 renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 
 // Add the canvas to the document
 renderer.domElement.style.backgroundColor = '#D6F1FF'; // easier to see
 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
 // Track mouse position so we know where to shoot
 document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
 
 // Shoot on click
 $(document).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  if (e.which === 1) { // Left click only
   createBullet();
  }
 });
 
 // Display HUD
 $('body').append('<canvas id="radar" width="200" height="200"></canvas>');
 $('body').append('<div id="hud"><p>Health: <span id="health">100</span><br />Score: <span id="score">0</span></p></div>');
 $('body').append('<div id="credits"><p>Created by <a href="http://www.isaacsukin.com/">Isaac Sukin</a> using <a href="http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/">Three.js</a><br />WASD to move, mouse to look, click to shoot</p></div>');
 
 // Set up "hurt" flash
 $('body').append('<div id="hurt"></div>');
 $('#hurt').css({width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT,});
}

// Helper function for browser frames
function animate() {
 if (runAnim) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 }
 render();
}

// Update and display
function render() {
 var delta = clock.getDelta(), speed = delta * BULLETMOVESPEED;
 var aispeed = delta * MOVESPEED;
 controls.update(delta); // Move camera
 
 // Rotate the health cube
 healthcube.rotation.x += 0.004
 healthcube.rotation.y += 0.008;
 // Allow picking it up once per minute
 if (Date.now() > lastHealthPickup + 60000) {
  if (distance(cam.position.x, cam.position.z, healthcube.position.x, healthcube.position.z) < 15 && health != 100) {
   health = Math.min(health + 50, 100);
   $('#health').html(health);
   lastHealthPickup = Date.now();
  }
  healthcube.material.wireframe = false;
 }
 else {
  healthcube.material.wireframe = true;
 }

 // Update bullets. Walk backwards through the list so we can remove items.
 for (var i = bullets.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var b = bullets[i], p = b.position, d = b.ray.direction;
  if (checkWallCollision(p)) {
   bullets.splice(i, 1);
   scene.remove(b);
   continue;
  }
  // Collide with AI
  var hit = false;
  for (var j = ai.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
   var a = ai[j];
   var v = a.geometry.vertices[0];
   var c = a.position;
   var x = Math.abs(v.x), z = Math.abs(v.z);
   //console.log(Math.round(p.x), Math.round(p.z), c.x, c.z, x, z);
   if (p.x < c.x + x && p.x > c.x - x &&
     p.z < c.z + z && p.z > c.z - z &&
     b.owner != a) {
    bullets.splice(i, 1);
    scene.remove(b);
    a.health -= PROJECTILEDAMAGE;
    var color = a.material.color, percent = a.health / 100;
    a.material.color.setRGB(
      percent * color.r,
      percent * color.g,
      percent * color.b
    );
    hit = true;
    break;
   }
  }
  // Bullet hits player
  if (distance(p.x, p.z, cam.position.x, cam.position.z) < 25 && b.owner != cam) {
   $('#hurt').fadeIn(75);
   health -= 10;
   if (health < 0) health = 0;
   val = health < 25 ? '<span style="color: darkRed">' + health + '</span>' : health;
   $('#health').html(val);
   bullets.splice(i, 1);
   scene.remove(b);
   $('#hurt').fadeOut(350);
  }
  if (!hit) {
   b.translateX(speed * d.x);
   //bullets[i].translateY(speed * bullets[i].direction.y);
   b.translateZ(speed * d.z);
  }
 }
 
 // Update AI.
 for (var i = ai.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var a = ai[i];
  if (a.health <= 0) {
   ai.splice(i, 1);
   scene.remove(a);
   kills++;
   $('#score').html(kills * 100);
   addAI();
  }
  // Move AI
  var r = Math.random();
  if (r > 0.995) {
   a.lastRandomX = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
   a.lastRandomZ = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  }
  a.translateX(aispeed * a.lastRandomX);
  a.translateZ(aispeed * a.lastRandomZ);
  var c = getMapSector(a.position);
  if (c.x < 0 || c.x >= mapW || c.y < 0 || c.y >= mapH || checkWallCollision(a.position)) {
   a.translateX(-2 * aispeed * a.lastRandomX);
   a.translateZ(-2 * aispeed * a.lastRandomZ);
   a.lastRandomX = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
   a.lastRandomZ = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
  }
  if (c.x < -1 || c.x > mapW || c.z < -1 || c.z > mapH) {
   ai.splice(i, 1);
   scene.remove(a);
   addAI();
  }
  /*
  var c = getMapSector(a.position);
  if (a.pathPos == a.path.length-1) {
   console.log('finding new path for '+c.x+','+c.z);
   a.pathPos = 1;
   a.path = getAIpath(a);
  }
  var dest = a.path[a.pathPos], proportion = (c.z-dest[1])/(c.x-dest[0]);
  a.translateX(aispeed * proportion);
  a.translateZ(aispeed * 1-proportion);
  console.log(c.x, c.z, dest[0], dest[1]);
  if (c.x == dest[0] && c.z == dest[1]) {
   console.log(c.x+','+c.z+' reached destination');
   a.PathPos++;
  }
  */
  var cc = getMapSector(cam.position);
  if (Date.now() > a.lastShot + 750 && distance(c.x, c.z, cc.x, cc.z) < 2) {
   createBullet(a);
   a.lastShot = Date.now();
  }
 }

 renderer.render(scene, cam); // Repaint
 
 // Death
 if (health <= 0) {
  runAnim = false;
  $(renderer.domElement).fadeOut();
  $('#radar, #hud, #credits').fadeOut();
  $('#intro').fadeIn();
  $('#intro').html('Ouch! Click to restart...');
  $('#intro').one('click', function() {
   location = location;
   /*
   $(renderer.domElement).fadeIn();
   $('#radar, #hud, #credits').fadeIn();
   $(this).fadeOut();
   runAnim = true;
   animate();
   health = 100;
   $('#health').html(health);
   kills--;
   if (kills <= 0) kills = 0;
   $('#score').html(kills * 100);
   cam.translateX(-cam.position.x);
   cam.translateZ(-cam.position.z);
   */
  });
 }
}

// Set up the objects in the world
function setupScene() {
 var UNITSIZE = 250, units = mapW;

 // Geometry: floor
 var floor = new t.Mesh(
   new t.CubeGeometry(units * UNITSIZE, 10, units * UNITSIZE),
   new t.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xEDCBA0,/*map: t.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/floor-1.jpg')*/})
 );
 scene.add(floor);
 
 // Geometry: walls
 var cube = new t.CubeGeometry(UNITSIZE, WALLHEIGHT, UNITSIZE);
 var materials = [
                  new t.MeshLambertMaterial({/*color: 0x00CCAA,*/map: t.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/wall-1.jpg')}),
                  new t.MeshLambertMaterial({/*color: 0xC5EDA0,*/map: t.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/wall-2.jpg')}),
                  new t.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xFBEBCD}),
                  ];
 for (var i = 0; i < mapW; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, m = map[i].length; j < m; j++) {
   if (map[i][j]) {
    var wall = new t.Mesh(cube, materials[map[i][j]-1]);
    wall.position.x = (i - units/2) * UNITSIZE;
    wall.position.y = WALLHEIGHT/2;
    wall.position.z = (j - units/2) * UNITSIZE;
    scene.add(wall);
   }
  }
 }
 
 // Health cube
 healthcube = new t.Mesh(
   new t.CubeGeometry(30, 30, 30),
   new t.MeshBasicMaterial({map: t.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/health.png')})
 );
 healthcube.position.set(-UNITSIZE-15, 35, -UNITSIZE-15);
 scene.add(healthcube);
 
 // Lighting
 var directionalLight1 = new t.DirectionalLight( 0xF7EFBE, 0.7 );
 directionalLight1.position.set( 0.5, 1, 0.5 );
 scene.add( directionalLight1 );
 var directionalLight2 = new t.DirectionalLight( 0xF7EFBE, 0.5 );
 directionalLight2.position.set( -0.5, -1, -0.5 );
 scene.add( directionalLight2 );
}

var ai = [];
var aiGeo = new t.CubeGeometry(40, 40, 40);
function setupAI() {
 for (var i = 0; i < NUMAI; i++) {
  addAI();
 }
}

function addAI() {
 var c = getMapSector(cam.position);
 var aiMaterial = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({/*color: 0xEE3333,*/map: t.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/face.png')});
 var object = new THREE.Mesh();
 
 var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
 loader.load( 'models/Tank.obj', function ( object ) {
   object.traverse( function ( child ) {
     if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
       child.material.map = aiMaterial;
     }
   } );
 } );    
 do {
  var x = getRandBetween(0, mapW-1);
  var z = getRandBetween(0, mapH-1);
 } while (map[x][z] > 0 || (x == c.x && z == c.z));
 x = Math.floor(x - mapW/2) * UNITSIZE;
 z = Math.floor(z - mapW/2) * UNITSIZE;
 object.position.set(x, UNITSIZE * 0.15, z);
 object.health = 100;
 //o.path = getAIpath(o);
 object.pathPos = 1;
 object.lastRandomX = Math.random();
 object.lastRandomZ = Math.random();
 object.lastShot = Date.now(); // Higher-fidelity timers aren't a big deal here.
 ai.push(object);
 scene.add(object);
}

function getAIpath(a) {
 var p = getMapSector(a.position);
 do { // Cop-out
  do {
   var x = getRandBetween(0, mapW-1);
   var z = getRandBetween(0, mapH-1);
  } while (map[x][z] > 0 || distance(p.x, p.z, x, z) < 3);
  var path = findAIpath(p.x, p.z, x, z);
 } while (path.length == 0);
 return path;
}

/**
 * Find a path from one grid cell to another.
 *
 * @param sX
 *   Starting grid x-coordinate.
 * @param sZ
 *   Starting grid z-coordinate.
 * @param eX
 *   Ending grid x-coordinate.
 * @param eZ
 *   Ending grid z-coordinate.
 * @returns
 *   An array of coordinates including the start and end positions representing
 *   the path from the starting cell to the ending cell.
 */
function findAIpath(sX, sZ, eX, eZ) {
 var backupGrid = grid.clone();
 var path = finder.findPath(sX, sZ, eX, eZ, grid);
 grid = backupGrid;
 return path;
}

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
 return Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
}

function getMapSector(v) {
 var x = Math.floor((v.x + UNITSIZE / 2) / UNITSIZE + mapW/2);
 var z = Math.floor((v.z + UNITSIZE / 2) / UNITSIZE + mapW/2);
 return {x: x, z: z};
}

/**
 * Check whether a Vector3 overlaps with a wall.
 *
 * @param v
 *   A THREE.Vector3 object representing a point in space.
 *   Passing cam.position is especially useful.
 * @returns {Boolean}
 *   true if the vector is inside a wall; false otherwise.
 */
function checkWallCollision(v) {
 var c = getMapSector(v);
 return map[c.x][c.z] > 0;
}

// Radar
function drawRadar() {
 var c = getMapSector(cam.position), context = document.getElementById('radar').getContext('2d');
 context.font = '10px Helvetica';
 for (var i = 0; i < mapW; i++) {
  for (var j = 0, m = map[i].length; j < m; j++) {
   var d = 0;
   for (var k = 0, n = ai.length; k < n; k++) {
    var e = getMapSector(ai[k].position);
    if (i == e.x && j == e.z) {
     d++;
    }
   }
   if (i == c.x && j == c.z && d == 0) {
    context.fillStyle = '#0000FF';
    context.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, (i+1)*20, (j+1)*20);
   }
   else if (i == c.x && j == c.z) {
    context.fillStyle = '#AA33FF';
    context.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, (i+1)*20, (j+1)*20);
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillText(''+d, i*20+8, j*20+12);
   }
   else if (d > 0 && d < 10) {
    context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
    context.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, (i+1)*20, (j+1)*20);
    context.fillStyle = '#000000';
    context.fillText(''+d, i*20+8, j*20+12);
   }
   else if (map[i][j] > 0) {
    context.fillStyle = '#666666';
    context.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, (i+1)*20, (j+1)*20);
   }
   else {
    context.fillStyle = '#CCCCCC';
    context.fillRect(i * 20, j * 20, (i+1)*20, (j+1)*20);
   }
  }
 }
}

var bullets = [];
var sphereMaterial = new t.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x333333});
var sphereGeo = new t.SphereGeometry(2, 6, 6);
function createBullet(obj) {
 if (obj === undefined) {
  obj = cam;
 }
 var sphere = new t.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMaterial);
 sphere.position.set(obj.position.x, obj.position.y * 0.8, obj.position.z);

 if (obj instanceof t.Camera) {
  var vector = new t.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1);
  projector.unprojectVector(vector, obj);
  sphere.ray = new t.Ray(
    obj.position,
    vector.subSelf(obj.position).normalize()
  );
 }
 else {
  var vector = cam.position.clone();
  sphere.ray = new t.Ray(
    obj.position,
    vector.subSelf(obj.position).normalize()
  );
 }
 sphere.owner = obj;
 
 bullets.push(sphere);
 scene.add(sphere);
 
 return sphere;
}

/*
function loadImage(path) {
 var image = document.createElement('img');
 var texture = new t.Texture(image, t.UVMapping);
 image.onload = function() { texture.needsUpdate = true; };
 image.src = path;
 return texture;
}
*/

function onDocumentMouseMove(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 mouse.x = (e.clientX / WIDTH) * 2 - 1;
 mouse.y = - (e.clientY / HEIGHT) * 2 + 1;
}

// Handle window resizing
$(window).resize(function() {
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
 if (cam) {
  cam.aspect = ASPECT;
  cam.updateProjectionMatrix();
 }
 if (renderer) {
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 }
 $('#intro, #hurt').css({width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT,});
});

// Stop moving around when the window is unfocused (keeps my sanity!)
$(window).focus(function() {
 if (controls) controls.freeze = false;
});
$(window).blur(function() {
 if (controls) controls.freeze = true;
});

//Get a random integer between lo and hi, inclusive.
//Assumes lo and hi are integers and lo is lower than hi.
function getRandBetween(lo, hi) {
 return parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*(hi-lo+1))+lo, 10);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>WebGL FPS - AngelHack SV 2012 - Isaac Sukin</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url('images/screenshot.jpg');
      cursor: crosshair;
      font-family: Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    #hud {
      bottom: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 10px;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    #credits {
      font-size: 12px;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      top: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    p {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    #radar {
      background-color: #EEEEEE;
      border: 1px solid black;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 100;
    }
    #intro {
      background-color: #000000;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 32px;
      opacity: 0.7;
      padding: 120px;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 1001;
    }
    #hurt {
      background-color: red;
      display: none;
      left: 0;
      opacity: 0.15;
      pointer-events: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1002;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="PointerLock.js"></script> --> <!-- Insufficient browser support, interferes with other mouse events -->
  <!-- <script src="Pathfinder.js"></script> -->
  <script src="Three.js"></script>
  <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="ColladaLoader.js"></script> -->
  <script src="Three.FirstPersonControls.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope anyone out there can help!

Thanks,
Noah

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Three.js the `subSelf` function was renamed to [`sub()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js#L163), so you need to update the code to be:

```
sphere.ray = new t.Ray(
  obj.position,
  vector.sub(obj.position).normalize()
);
```